# convert complex sql to elasticsearch query

Tags: sql, elasticsearch

Now I have a index and a type(test_type),mapping like this

```
{A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,Z}
```

And my sql is

```
select A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,count(*) as a_count,sum(Z) as z_sum from test_type group by A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I
```

How can I convert this sql to es query?

Comment: That depends on how your index is structured

Comment: this can be useful too: https://www.elastic.co/de/blog/an-introduction-to-elasticsearch-sql-with-practical-examples-part-1

Comment: would you please tell me what is how my index is structured... and my es cluster version is 5.5.0,es sql is not support at this version.. @SergejSchelle